# Stuck in creating a Dice-Roller

Tags: python, try-except

I am creating a D&D Dice-Roller for me to use, and I have a problem. I want to be able to roll absurd amounts of dice. As such, I need to know where the quantity part should end, and where the type part of the dice should start. [I type the roll in the following way: 2d8 (Quantity d Type)]. When I try to use the .index() function to find the 'd' character, I can't get it to run correctly. 
Thank you for your time, even if you just read this.

```
import random

def rollDice(quant, type):
    Troll = 0
    for roll in range(quant):
        Troll += (random.randrange(type) + 1)
    print("You rolled: " + str(Troll))

def check(user):
    sep = user.lower().index('d') #I get the problem when I use this
    try:
        quant = int(user[0:sep])
        type = int(user[sep:])
        if type in (4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100):
            rollDice(quant, type)
        else:
            print("Not valid dice type!")
    except:
        print("Invalid Input!")

while True:
    print("To exit type [EXIT]")
    user = input("Enter what you want to roll[e.x: 2d8]: ")
    if user.upper() == "EXIT":
        exit()
    else:
        check(user)
```

Comment: Try this: `quant, type = user.lower().split('d')`

Comment: `type = int(user[sep+1:])`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this would seem to fix the problem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: use: `quant, type = user.lower().split('d')` (instead of `sep =...`, `quant =...` and `type = ...`), but also inside the `try` block [then you'd convert the values to `int`].

Comment: And please! rename `Troll` to `total_roll`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to fix this:

```
def check(user):
    try:
        quant = int(user.lower().split('d')[0])
        type = int(user.lower().split('d')[1])
        if type in (4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 20, 100):
            rollDice(quant, type)
        else:
            print("Not valid dice type!")
    except:
        print("Invalid Input!")
```

Comment: You need to convert to `int`. Something like `quant, type = [int(x) for x in user.lower().split('d')]`